# Count all defined values in a DataFrame column where the corresponding values in another column are undefined in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, nan

I am working with a `DataFrame` with two columns constraint, such that when the first has a value defined, then the other should have the corresponding value defined as well. I would like to count the number of cases where this constraint is not holding.

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [np.nan, 2, np.nan, 4, 5, 6],'b': [11, 12 , np.nan, 14, 15, np.nan]})

     a    b
0  NaN   11
1    2   12
2  NaN  NaN
3    4   14
4    5   15
5    6  NaN
```

When the value in column `a` is defined, then the corresponding value in column `b` has to be defined as well. This does not hold for row with index `5`, so the result in this case should be `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
len(df.loc[(df.a.notnull()) & (df.b.isnull())])
```

The above finds all rows where `a` is not `NaN` and `b` is `NaN`, and `len()` just counts the number of rows in the resulting dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate a Boolean series and then use `pd.Series.sum`:

```
m1 = df['a'].notnull()
m2 = df['b'].isnull()
res = (m1 & m2).sum()
```

This works because Boolean values, when used in calculations, are considered `1` / `0` for `True` / `False` respectively.